# How to add a listener to a vue-multiselect after the page has loaded?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I need to add a listener to a vue-multiselect, like this *(but this does not work)*:

```
$('.multiselect').change(console.log("multiselect changed"));
```

### It must be added in the [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) hook.

I've tried a lot of things, but because of the nature of vue-multiselect, conventional jQuery doesn't work *ie, you can't listen for a change on the `multiselect__input` because its value doesn't actually change.*

There's a `.multiselect__single` element that is added\removed depending on the state, but I'd rather not listen\test for html changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [`vue-multiselect` events](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events) don't include `change`, but you're probably looking for `input` (emitted after the `value` changes) or `searchChanged` (emitted after the search query changes).

The idiomatic way to [listen to an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events) is to use this syntax: `@EVENTNAME="METHOD"`. Example:

```
<multiselect @input="onSelection">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSelection(newValue) {
      console.log({newValue})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <multiselect :options="options" v-model="value" @input="onSelection"></multiselect>
  <div>value: {{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I do that after the page has loaded?

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about timing in regards to setting an event listener, as Vue sets the event listener when it parses the template. Can you clarify why that's a concern?

Comment: I'm trying to force vue-multiselect to tab to the next tabindex (it doesn't do that right now) and I cannot add `@input` to each multiselect element (would be impossible to enforce). So I need to add a listener from a central location in the `updated` function. I mean that's the point of the entire question. I know about `@select` and `@input` and yes, that's what I need, but after the page has loaded, and each time updated is called.

Comment: That sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't think you understand what my problem is. Thanks anyway.